# Return value always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, return-value

I'm trying to implement GCD function using recursion, but when i make a return value, it always returns undefined, while if i made a console.log(value) it shows it correctly ?

here is the code i'm using:

```js
let a = 6
let b = 4

var gcd = gcdRec(a, b)
console.log(gcd) //this executes undefined



function gcdRec(a, b) {
  var gcd = 0
  if (a % b === 0) {
    gcd = b
    return gcd //if i used console.log(gcd) it prints correctly

  } else {
    var temp = b
    b = a % b
    a = temp
    if (b === 0) {
      gcd = a
      return gcd
    }
    gcdRec(a, b)
  }
}
```

I also tried to define gce before using it, as `let gcd =0` then `gcd = gcdRec(a,b)` , but it still the same. any idea why it's doing this ?

Comment: finally a return statement is missing before `gcdRec(a, b)`.

Comment: Think about what happens if neither the first nor the second `if` condition is true... Then there is nothing returned from the function.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know i have to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give return statement in function for each condition

```js
let a = 6
let b = 4

var gcd = gcdRec(a, b)
console.log(gcd) //this executes undefined



function gcdRec(a, b) {
  var gcd = 0
  if (a % b === 0) {
    gcd = b
    return gcd //if i used console.log(gcd) it prints correctly

  } else {
    var temp = b
    b = a % b
    a = temp
    if (b === 0) {
      gcd = a
      return gcd
    }
   return gcdRec(a, b)
  }
}
```